When using tiptap in react, a routing problem was encountered
When I jump from /editor to /, I get an error:
Unexpected Application Error!
Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
I don't know how to fix it. Here's my code:
Editor/index.tsx
import React from 'react'
import './editor.scss'
import { useEditor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/react'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import 'remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css'
import BubbleMenu from '@/components/Editor/BubbleMenu.tsx'
import FloatingMenu from '@/components/Editor/FloatingMenu.tsx'

const Editor: React.FC = () => {
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: '',
  })
  return (
    <>
      {editor && <BubbleMenu editor={editor} />}
      {editor && <FloatingMenu editor={editor} />}
      <div className={'editor-content'}>
        <EditorContent editor={editor} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Editor

Editor/BubbleMenu.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { BubbleMenu, Editor } from '@tiptap/react'
import classNames from 'classnames'

type Props = {
  editor: Editor
}
const BubbleMenuComponent = ({ editor }: Props) => {
  return (
      <BubbleMenu
          editor={editor}
          tippyOptions={{duration: 100}}
          className={'bubble-menu'}
      >
      
        <i
            onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()}
            className={classNames('cmd', 'ri-bold', {
              'is-active': editor.isActive('bold'),
            })}
        />
        
        <i
            onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleItalic().run()}
            className={classNames('cmd', 'ri-italic', {
              'is-active': editor.isActive('italic'),
            })}
        />
        
        <i
            onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleStrike().run()}
            className={classNames('cmd', 'ri-strikethrough', {
              'is-active': editor.isActive('strike'),
            })}
        />
      </BubbleMenu>
  )
}

export default BubbleMenuComponent

I want to know why and how to fix it. Thank you very much.
